# copyTo() vs clone() inside function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've just begun learning C++ and OpenCV. I'm trying to make my own function but I'm confused as to why `copyTo(dst);` works, but when I use `dst = src.clone();` the displayed output is black?

```
void testFunc(InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst){
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    _dst.create(src.size(), src.type());
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();
    src.copyTo(dst);
    // ^this works but
    // dst = src.clone(); doesn't
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think one way to resolve this issue is to treat `Mat` as a pointer (not quite correct, but humour me for a moment).

In your example you create `Mat src` which points to the source matrix.  You then create a matrix for the destination with `create(...)` and create a new *pointer* `Mat dst` to this new matrix.  When you use `src.copyTo(dst)`, OpenCV copies the data pointed to by `src` into the target pointed to by `dst`, however when you use the assignment `dst = src.clone()`, `dst` is replaced with a clone of `src` (that is, the pointer is changed to a new location).

With basic types, this could translate to something like:

```
struct Input { int* data; };
struct Output { int* data; };

void testFunc(Input _src, Output _dst)
{
    int* src = _src.data;
    _dst.data = new int;
    int* dst = _dst.data;

    // src.copyTo(dst)
    *dst = *src;

    // dst = src.clone()
    dst = new int(*src);
}
```

This way of thinking about it is not entirely correct, but it might be useful for thinking about this behaviour.